# aura:iteration and calling JS controller function each pass

Tags: javascript, lightning

Is it possible to directly call a Lightning component controller function during each aura:iteration? I have everything stored as custom metadata and the Apex controller filters out the sObjects that match the criteria. I pass the List attribute into the JS controller which loops to look if the current iterated item is in the list and if so, enable the field. I was wanting something like,

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.allAPIFields}" var="item">

    <!-- CALL CDEContentDocDetailsController.FindFieldsUpdate HERE? -->

    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div id="inputFieldsCol1" class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal_medium">
            <lightning:input label="{!item}"
                             aura:id="fieldInput"
                             disabled="{!isDisabled}"/>
        </div>
        <div id="inputFieldsCol2" class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal_medium">
            <lightning:input label="{!item}"
                             aura:id="fieldInput"
                             disabled="{!isDisabled}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

My only other thought was to build a map and hoping I could use a "CONTAINS" in my component?

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't call a method like that during the iteration. I'd imagine it probably be a huge performance sink anyways. You'll want to process the data in your controller/helper and then set the value. Something like this:

```
<aura:iteration items="{!v.allAPIFields}" var="item">
    <div class="slds-grid">
        <div id="inputFieldsCol1" class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal_medium">
            <lightning:input label="{!item.label}"
                             aura:id="fieldInput"
                             disabled="{!item.isDisabled}"/>
        </div>
        <div id="inputFieldsCol2" class="slds-col slds-p-horizontal_medium">
            <lightning:input label="{!item.label}"
                             aura:id="fieldInput"
                             disabled="{!item.isDisabled}"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</aura:iteration>
```

To actually map the data, use Array.prototype.map:

```
 allAPIFields = allAPIFields.map(function(item) { return { label: item, isDisabled: FindFieldsUpdate(item) } });
```

I'm not sure what that method is supposed to look like, but it sounds like you may also want to bulkify the method, especially if you're calling the server repeatedly.